# pager (less) -- get current scroll position?

Tags: shell, unix, tmux, pager, less-unix

I am scripting the display of the output of a script (well, it is just the program `git diff`) with tmux: Once a filesystem change is detected the shell script executes `tmux send-keys q enter C-l "git diff" enter` which has it effectively refresh the `git diff` view.

You might consider this similar to functionality provided by [iTerm's coprocesses](http://www.iterm2.com/coprocesses.html#/section/home).

Problem is, I want it on refresh to scroll back to the same position that it was in.

One of the reasons for using tmux is that the window is actually a totally normal and interactive terminal session that can be interacted with as normal to scroll around to look at the full output.

But I want to obtain the scroll position somehow.

Suppose I want to actually do computation on the text content of the terminal window itself, exactly like iTerm2's coprocess does, but so that I can use it on Linux (over ssh). Does tmux provide this ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about capturing this with a script, but `less -N` will show line numbers.
And `-jn` or `--jump-target=n` can jump to a location.

Comment: cool, thanks. for my actual implementation I have actually given up on less and am now using `tmux` in a crazy way in order to get mouse scrolling.

Comment: @StevenLu willing to share details on how you do it?

Comment: it's basically as I describe in the question, I just now force git diff not to use `less`. this way mouse scrolling works automatically in the (potentially nested) tmux buffer

Comment: I've circled back to this, the gymnastics that i had to use to manipulate the nested tmux session was unmanageable, and even more so in the face of tmux itself evolving. I am thinking now about either implementing my own augmented less or similarly wrapping a manipulator around it.

Answer (score 0):

About iTerm's coprocesses,

`tmux` has a command `pipe-pane` that can be used to pipe the input and output of a shell command to the output and input of a target pane specified by `-t`.

So if I have a shell program, `~/script.sh` for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" = "are you there?"* ]]; then
        echo "echo yes"
    fi
done
```

Note that `read line` will read every line printed to the pane, i.e. the prompt as well.

I can connect its stdin and stdout to pane 0 in `my-session:my-window` like so:

```
tmux pipe-pane -IO -t my-session:my-window.0 "~/script.sh"
```

and then at the prompt, type `echo are you there?`, and it responds:

```
$ echo are you there?
are you there?
$ echo yes
yes
```

Be careful using `-IO` together as it can easily cause a feedback loop (I had to kill the tmux server a few times while experimenting with this feature, lol).